# push() a two-dimensional array for date

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, push

I'm trying to push to a two-dimensional array, currently My array is:

```
[2020, 11, 16]
[2020, 11, 17]
[2020, 11, 19]
[2020, 11, 16]
[2020, 11, 17]
[2020, 11, 19]
```

and my Code is

```
 totalDate = xyz.length;


 // var output = []; 


     for (var o = 0; o < totalDate; o++) {
        date = xyz[o].split(',');
        for(var a=0; a<date.length; a++) { 

            date[a] = parseInt(date[a], 10); 
        }

        console.log(date);
     
     }
```

That should result in the following:

```
  var dates = [[2020, 11, 16], [2020, 11, 17], [2020, 11, 19], [2020, 11, 16], [2020, 11, 17], [2020, 11, 19]];
```

Comment: You  current array and expected result is same. Please give all the information.

Comment: The data you are showing above  must also be in a data structure ? Where are those arrays stored ? Is it in an array or an object ?

Comment: you are doing wrong operation as split over array, don't need to split, without split it gives you same result as you want for date.length

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
var output = []; 
for (var o = 0; o < totalDate; o++) {
        date = xyz[o].split(',');
        for(var a=0; a<date.length; a++) { 

            date[a] = parseInt(date[a], 10); 
        }
        output.push(date);
        console.log(date);
     
     }

console.log(output);
```